# Comparison of trends over time

Tags: panel-data, trend, test-for-trend

I am studying trends of a certain outcome between two populations. Although both populations show decreasing incidence, I would like to see whether the rates of change are different between both populations. Is there a statistical test to accomplish this? Any advice would be helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: This is a bit vague. It might be easier to fix the process modelled and if trend is uniform. If they are both decreasing with certainty, one can simply compute the slopes naively.